# HQL Query with LEFT JOIN and WHERE not giving results

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Working with HQL, on this simplified scenario:

```
String query =  "SELECT new CustomUser(" +
                "user.userID AS id," +
                "user.username AS username)" +
                "FROM User AS user" +
                " LEFT JOIN user.friends as friend " +
                " where user.username like (:query)" +
                " OR " +
                " friend.username like (:query) ";
```

This is giving back only those Users that have at least one friend, but I want to get Users by a condition, beyond of having Friends or not.

- Dynamic instantiation is used because of domain requirements
- I've noticed that it gives all Users, having Friends or not, if there is no condition on the joined table (*friend.username like (:query)*)

These are my tables:

**User**

```
@Id...
protected Integer userID;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Friend> friends;
```

**Friend**

```
    @Id
    private Integer friendID;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    private User user;
```

- Note: it works as I expect on native SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query.
`String query =  "SELECT new CustomUser(" +
                "user.userID AS id," +
                "user.username AS username)" +
                "FROM User AS user" +
                " LEFT OUTER JOIN user.friends as friend " +
                " where user.username like (:query)" +
                " OR " +
                " friend.username like (:query) ";`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same